# How can I schedule some work every day between 12 am to 6 pm with a 60 minute interval in Android?

Tags: java, android

This is my code for making a call at 3 pm every day:

```java
long INTERVAL_MSEC = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

Date date2am = new java.util.Date();
date2am.setHours(15);
date2am.setMinutes(0);        

Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        String finalPhonenumber = Globals.sms1PhoneNumbers.get(rad).number + getResources().getString(R.string.extention);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + finalPhonenumber));
        startActivity(callIntent);
    }
};

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, date2am, INTERVAL_MSEC);
```

Now I need to make a call everyday between 12 am to 6 pm with 60 minutes interval - how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Are you sure that I can define time duration in Alarm Manager.

Comment: have a look at Firebase Job Dispatcher https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android

Comment: imo cronjob is used on unix based system to do these kind of things. what you can do is set alarm to call your service at 12 am (you can get number of seconds from now to that time period.) Now set next alarm for 60 minutes and then for 6 hours. (in you alarm setter, you can get current time to know what time delta should be given).

Comment: Do you need this to run everyday ?

Comment: Every day between 12 am -6 pm

Comment: you can have multiple alarms set: 1) 12 am to start doing the task. In the end of each task check, if it is not 6 pm still, then schedule next task in a hour with Alarm manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create An alarm as created below that runs at 12 a.m or 00:00 hours :

```
 private void startat12() {
    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 00);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);

    Long milliseconds = c.getTimeInMillis();
    Long daily = 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L;

    //check if the time is already passed
    if (milliseconds < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        //if already passed then push it for next day by adding just 24 hrs
        milliseconds = milliseconds + daily;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(YourActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, milliseconds, pendingIntent);
    } else {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, milliseconds, pendingIntent);
    }
    String dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm is set for " + formatter.format(milliseconds), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Now your `MyReceiver` will receive a Broadcast at 00:00 hours the next day 
The code for your receiver will be :

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

PowerManager powerManager;
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
AlarmManager alarmManager;
Calendar c;
SimpleDateFormat formatter;
String dateFormat;


@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    //acquire wake lock
    powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakelockTag");
    wakeLock.acquire();

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    Long daily = 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L;
    //Set Unlocked notification broadcast
    Intent intentnew= new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentnew, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm";
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm is set for " + formatter.format(c.getTimeInMillis()+daily), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (c.getTimeInMillis() + daily), pendingIntent);
    } else {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (c.getTimeInMillis() + daily), pendingIntent);
    }

    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //DO your Work for each Hour
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            String finalPhonenumber = Globals.sms1PhoneNumbers.get(rad).number + context.getResources().getString(R.string.extention);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + finalPhonenumber));
            context.startActivity(callIntent);
            Toast.makeText(context, "It Ran", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Also post your mHandler for next hour

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() < c.getTimeInMillis()) {
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 60L * 60L * 1000L);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Task will repeat after an hour", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    };

    c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    mHandler.post(mRunnable);

    wakeLock.release();
}
```

}

And Do include the permission for wake lock in your manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

also your receiver :

```
<receiver android:name=".Notificationtwo.MyReceiver"/>
```